# Horizontally centering Bootstrap elements that use the an odd span width

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

This seems to be a common problem in the Bootstrap community, the process of centering and class with an odd number for the span width, `class="span3"` for example.  I have a `.row` with three `.span3` classes inside it.  I realize it would be easier to just use three `span4` classes, but I'm not a fan of how large it makes my elements.

I've tried a few things so far:

1. I've created a custom 15-column grid so I could give a `.span3` class before and after the three elements I actually want to use, however when `responsive-bootstrap.css` kicks in, things act strange because the responsive file deals with a 12-column grid.
2. I've tried placing everything in a custom `.center` class which uses the following CSS:

   ```
   .center {
       float: none;
       margin: 0 auto;
       text-align: center;
   }
   ```

For what it's worth, everything works when my browser width is between ~980px - ~1199px.

There has to be a simple way to fix this problem, right?  I'm not worried about it looking good on older browsers either, this is a personal site.  Here is where I'm currently at, working with a 15-column grid:

**Here is my [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yeQUZ/)**

The HTML:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="center">
           <ul class="thumbnails" id="portfolio-links">
                <li class="span3"></li>
                <li class="span3" id="item1">
                    <a href="#" class="thumbnail" id="portfolio-element"></a>
                </li>
                <li class="span3" id="item2">
                    <a href="#" class="thumbnail" id="portfolio-element"></a>
                </li>
                <li class="span3" id="item3">
                    <a href="#" class="thumbnail" id="portfolio-element"></a>
                </li>
                <li class="span3"></li>
           </ul><!--/.thumbnails-->
    </div><!--/.center-->
</div><!--/.row-->
```

The CSS:

```
#portfolio-links {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    float: none;
}
.center {
    float: none;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: Do you want something like http://jsfiddle.net/AKWqP/?

Comment: @Pigueiras Yes, that seems to be what I am looking for!  If you post an answer I'll go ahead an accept it...  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just have to make the `<div class="center">` with a size of `span9` and remove the extra `li`.

The final result will be: http://jsfiddle.net/AKWqP/